# Save Custom TextBox Content

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

How can I change the visual appearance of my TextBox without affecting the functionality?

Here is my XAML code for the TB:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" 
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Background="Beige"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Height="100" Width="250"
                             Margin="10"
                             Style="{StaticResource tbTheme}"/>
```

Here is the resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="tbTheme" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

                    <Border x:Name="tb_Border"
                            Padding="5"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="3"
                            CornerRadius="10">


                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                                 ClipToBounds="True"
                                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
                                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                        
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And here is the Save Button Implementation:

```
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileRoot = @"G:\VS_Projekte\C#\WPF\Modern_UI\tb_Data\";

        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileRoot);

        if (tb1.Text != "")
        {
            textWriter.Write(tb1.Text.ToString());
            textWriter.Flush();
        }

        textWriter.Close();
        tb1.Clear();

     

    }
```

The problem with this setup is that tb1.Text is always Empty.
I guess the Problem lies in a fals Binding direction of the TextBox inside the Style but i dont know how to make it better.

I would appreciate if you could tell me the reason why this is not working and show me a solid solution to solve this kind of problem in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A TextBox in the ControlTemplate of a TextBox makes no sense. There should be `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />`. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: That Name in the scrollviewer is used in code for the textbox control to decide which part of the control the user enters text into.  If you look at the source code for Textboxbase you'll see it referenced: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/TextBoxBase.cs,52a329d42544a8fc

Comment: Thank you both. You helped me out a lot !

Answer (score 0):

When there is not enough experience in creating custom templates, it is better to get the default element template and make changes to it.

An example of a template based on the Default TextBox template (I hope I did not miss the details that are important for you):

```xml
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            
        <!--Standard values from Default Template-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            
        <!--Custom values.
        If there are several setters for one property, then the last one will be taken into account.
        In practical application, the previous ones must be removed.
        I did not do this to make it easier to understand the logic of the work.-->
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            CornerRadius="10">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                        Focusable="false"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```